# Convert anomaly scores to probabilities in a one-class way

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, anomaly-detection

Im trying to convert anomaly scores into into probabilities. I wanted to do this with logistic regression. The problem is that I can only provide labels for non-anomalous training examples. Training the logistic regression model does not work, training examples need to be provided for two classes.

Is there another way to do this conversion if only data for the normal case is known apriori?

Thank you.

Comment: How are anomaly scores calculated? PS: you might want to look into Out-of-Distribution detection techniques. But knowing more details would be helpful in order to answer your question.

Comment: Hi. So the scores come from different algorithms that are very different in nature. If I can convert them to probabilities it would be easier to combine them and interpret them.

Comment: Without more information, I would say that i) from the training data, you may infer the probability density $P(\text{score}|\text{not anomalous})=P(s|NA)$; then ii) you can then make hypotheses about $P(\text{score}|\text{anomalous})=P(s|A)$, and $P(A)$, the overall probability of anomalous events.
From these you can derive the following target probability of something being anomalous given its score:
$$
P(A|s) = \frac{P(s|A)P(A)}{P(s)} = \frac{P(s|A)P(A)}{P(s|A)P(A) + P(s|NA)P(NA)}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am not to familiar with these concepts. Can you point me to a e.g. a specific function on how this can be computed in python?

Comment: Forgot: Can this be done if you only have normal data available for the training/calibration ?